# Applying column permissions for a table over a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, relational-database

For now, i have a table called members, which contains stuff, which is splitted in conact datas, bank datas....
Now, the admin should be able to create, update, delete users, which are saved in another table, which can only access the administrator. The users should get their own mysql user account and the admins should also be able to set permissions, like that users arent able to access bank datas.
For now, I made a trigger, which creates and deletes the user accounts. Now I wanted to apply the permissions over a trigger, but I didnt find a promising solution
I tought already about setting column permissions, but If i want to add a column, I would have another thing, which i would have to edit in this case.
I also tought about 1:1 Relationships, but I didnt find a working code.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: don't give your users direct access to the database.  They should never be able to connect.  Only the people responsible for maintenance and operations should have access to the production database.  This is for security reasons.  In almost every case where information is stored in a database, there is an application which controls all access, it handles doing the actual updates, and it enforces the business logic that you choose.

Don't mix data with business logic.

There are some database systems, such as Oracle which excel at letting your store and apply much of your business logic inside the database itself.  However, this is for a different type of application, and a different approach to building systems.

MySQL doesn't have all those tools to make doing this as easy.  Trust me when I tell you that you're setting yourself up for a maintenance nightmare if you try to write your application logic in triggers and stored procedures and views, then give your users direct access to the database.

When was the last time you were given direct database access when you signed up for something?  Twitter, Netflix, Groupon, Facebook -- you're interacting with a web-based application which applies the business rules and reads and writes data into the database on your behalf.

There are plenty of tools which make writing your application software easier: debugging, profiling, source control for code and collaborative development, unit testing, continuous integration and deployment tools.  If you try to write everything into the database, you'll lose all of that.

Here's a quick example of how this would work:

Structure your permissions system as three tables: user, group, user_group.  User holds the user accounts in you system, group holds the various levels of access such as "admin", "client", "anonymous", etc.  Groups are how you assign access levels to users.

```
`CREATE TABLE `user` (
`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_group` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
```

Now to define some groups

```
`insert into `group` (name) values ('admin'), ('user'), ('anonymous');`
```

And a user, then add them to the admin group:

```
`insert into user (email) values ('admin@yoursite.com');`
`insert into user_group (user_id,group_id) values (1,1);`
```

Now this permissions model says that a user can belong to one or more security groups.  You application would check for those groups and preform different actions based on the results.    Let's see some psuedo-code:

Load a user's groups:

```
class User {

  private $user_id;
  private $groups;
  private $db;

  function load_groups() {
    // query the database
    $result = $db->query("SELECT name FROM `group` g JOIN user_group ug USING (group_id) WHERE user_id={$this->user_id}");
    // save an array of group names
    while ($row = $result->fetchrow()) {
      $this->groups[] = $row['name'];
    }
  }

  function is_member($group) {
    if (in_array($group, $this->groups) {
      return true;  // user group includes this value
    }
    return false;  // user is not in the group
 }
```

Now in your application, you might have a function to view the data, but it would produce different results depending on the user's groups:

```
function display_data($user_object) {
   display_basic_data();   // everyone sees the basic data
   if ($user_object->is_member('admin')) {  
     // if the user is an admin, then display bank data too
     display_bank_data();
   }
}
```

Similarly, your functions to modify data should verify that the users has permissions to change things.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this is not a web application, it is a desktop application for a small group of users. First, I programmed it for one User only with SQLite, then they wanted to run this in their LAN, so I set up a network storage and all user accessed over lan. Now they wanted to access their datas in the internet, so i ported this (it was a single user app) to mysql and i wanted to  make it secure with triggers/users, cause it is much easier than serving datas over something like php scripts.Is there maybe another solution like a mysql proxy,so that i can use the mysql connector?

Comment: this is not a trigger concept at all

Comment: Of course not.  A trigger is not the right way to solve this problem.